# TestNG global @AfterMethod

Tags: java, annotations, testng

In java TestNG is it possible to somehow specify a global (or suite wide) method with `@AfterMethod` annotation? 
The goal is to have different test cases in separate classes(so that 1 file = 1 test) but to also have a common `@AfterMethod` without duplicating the method in every class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making a superclass. Example:

```
public class BasicTestScenario {

  @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
  public void tearDown() {
    // your implementation
  }
}
```

Then have your tests inherit this class.

```
public class MyTest extends BasicTestScenario {
// your test
}
```

Comment: This is too perfect. Really silly too! Thanks a lot!